# Detect the image is blurred or not in React-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am using [VisionCamera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) (package name *react-native-vision-camera*) to capture images. When I capture the image, I need this information image blur, white/black balance, reflection, etc.

How can I do it? Is there a library to solve this issue?